# Set width of SWT Table Column

Tags: java, swt, tablecolumn

I'm adding column one by one to my swt table. with

```
int totalwidth=0;
for(String s:phoneErrs){
    TableColumn tblclmnError = new TableColumn(tablephone, SWT.CENTER);
    tblclmnError.setText(s);
    tblclmnError.pack();
    totalwidth+=tblclmnError.getWidth();
}
```

and after this I want to add a last column, that should fill the rest of the
space in table header. Now that I have the total width of the added columns
already, I should be able to calculate the width of my last column and specify
it right? but how? I tried

```
TableColumn tblclmnComment = new TableColumn(tablephone, SWT.CENTER);
tblclmnComment.setWidth(tablephone.getSize().x-totalwidth);
tblclmnComment.setText("Comment");
```

but it's not working. the `getSize()` return `0`.

Comment: Did you created in on the composite?

Comment: on a composite which contains more stuffs.

Comment: please tell me more in detail. Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [SWT - table layout - Resize the column of a table to fill all the available space](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9211106/swt-table-layout-resize-the-column-of-a-table-to-fill-all-the-available-spac)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by adding listener on `SWT.Resize` event type.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Display display = new Display();
        final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, true));

        TableViewer viewer1 = getViewer(shell);

        List<String> rows = new ArrayList<String>();
        rows.add("Row 1");
        rows.add("Row 2");

        viewer1.setInput(rows);

        shell.pack();
        shell.open();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                display.sleep();
            }
        }
        display.dispose();
    }

    private static TableViewer getViewer(final Shell shell) {
        TableViewer viewer = new TableViewer(shell, SWT.FULL_SELECTION
                | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.NONE);

        viewer.getTable().addListener(SWT.Resize, new Listener() {

          @Override
          public void handleEvent(Event event) {


            Table table = (Table)event.widget;
            int columnCount = table.getColumnCount();
            if(columnCount == 0)
              return;
            Rectangle area = table.getClientArea();
            int totalAreaWdith = area.width;
            int lineWidth = table.getGridLineWidth();
            int totalGridLineWidth = (columnCount-1)*lineWidth; 
            int totalColumnWidth = 0;
            for(TableColumn column: table.getColumns())
            {
              totalColumnWidth = totalColumnWidth+column.getWidth();
            }
            int diff = totalAreaWdith-(totalColumnWidth+totalGridLineWidth);

            TableColumn lastCol = table.getColumns()[columnCount-1];

//check diff is valid or not. setting negetive width doesnt make sense.
            lastCol.setWidth(diff+lastCol.getWidth());

          }
        });

        viewer.setContentProvider(ArrayContentProvider.getInstance());

        viewer.getTable().setLayoutData(
                new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

        TableViewerColumn col = new TableViewerColumn(viewer, SWT.NONE);
        col.getColumn().setWidth(100);
        col.getColumn().setText("Text Column");
        col.setLabelProvider(new ColumnLabelProvider() {
            @Override
            public void update(ViewerCell cell) {
                cell.setText((String) cell.getElement());
            }
        });

        col = new TableViewerColumn(viewer, SWT.NONE);
        col.getColumn().setWidth(100);
        col.getColumn().setText("Second Text Column");
        col.setLabelProvider(new ColumnLabelProvider() {
            @Override
            public void update(ViewerCell cell) {
                cell.setText((String) cell.getElement());
            }
        });


        viewer.getTable().setHeaderVisible(true);

        return viewer;
    }
```