# How can I make the columns fill all the table?

Tags: java, plugins, swt, jface

I have created a tableViewer that contains a table with two columns. The fact is that the two columns don´t fill all the table area and I want to create two columns with same proportions to fill it.

**Code:**

```
TableViewer viewer = new TableViewer(createProjectConfig, SWT.MULTI | SWT.H_SCROLL| SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.FULL_SELECTION | SWT.BORDER);
TableViewerColumn viewerColumn = new TableViewerColumn(viewer, SWT.NONE);
TableViewerColumn viewerColumn1 = new TableViewerColumn(viewer, SWT.NONE);

Table createVariablesTable = viewer.getTable();
createVariablesTable.setLayoutData(new FormData());
createVariablesTable.setHeaderVisible(true);
createVariablesTable.setLinesVisible(true);

FormData createVariablesTableData = new FormData();
createVariablesTableData.left = new FormAttachment(selectProjectPathLabel, 0, SWT.LEFT);
createVariablesTableData.top = new FormAttachment(selectProjectPathLabel, 40, SWT.TOP);
createVariablesTableData.right = new FormAttachment(selectProjectPathButton,0,SWT.RIGHT);
createVariablesTableData.bottom = new FormAttachment(createProjectConfigButton,-10,SWT.TOP);
createVariablesTable.setLayoutData(createVariablesTableData);

TableColumn column = viewerColumn.getColumn();
column.setText("${Variable}");
column.setWidth(50);//Make this fill the half of the table
column.setResizable(true);
column.setMoveable(true);

TableColumn column1 = viewerColumn1.getColumn();
column1.setText("${AAA}");
column1.setWidth(50);//Make this fill the half of the table
column1.setResizable(true);
column1.setMoveable(true);
```

**Image:**

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9211106/resize-the-column-of-a-table-to-fill-all-the-available-space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set a table layout for the table.

```
TableLayout tableLayout = new TableLayout();
createVariablesTable.setLayout(tableLayout);
```

Then for each column set a column weight:

```
tableLayout.addColumnData(new ColumnWeightData(50));

tableLayout.addColumnData(new ColumnWeightData(50));
```

Also remove the calls to `column.setWidth(50)`

Comment: Hi, setColumnData was giving me problems (it appears not to be defined as TableLayout method) and I have used addColumnData to make it work: 
        tableLayout.addColumnData(new ColumnWeightData(50));

Comment: Sorry, it should be `addColumnData`. `setColumnData` is for the slightly more compliced `TableColumnLayout`. Updated answer.

Comment: Thank you, you are helping me a lot! I have seen the link that Baz has posted below my comment but it uses TableColumnLayout to maintain the proportions of the column when resizing the window. Is there any way to make the same with TableLayout or I should follow that example?

Comment: Use `TableColumnLayout` if you want the better handling of resizing. The main difference is that the layout must be set on a `Composite` that has the table as its only child.